# Product description page not shown, error 404

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

using magento 1.7.0.2 here, having already tested lot of recommended solutions (reindexing, clearing cache, assuring no url rewrite is done, etc) I give up and ask the question.

We are importing a bunch of products (around 150) into the demo store, together with 2 new categories and lot of new attributes (around 200). After some issues we finally managed to get the products shown both on backend and frontend, great.

But when clicking on any newly imported product we get the 404 error page from Magento with the "Whoops, our bad...". After 2 days searching and trying different approaches still haven't found a solution. Reindexing, clearing cache, checking the url rewrite option, changing 'localhost' for '127.0.0.1' on the core_config_data table, and some other solutions that worked for others, no use for us.

Any clue?

Other than the solutions found we have checked that the products are enabled, visibility is set for both catalog and search, there is a website assigned and quantity is bigger than zero. Also we manually created a product with all the correct attributes values and its description page is visible. Comparing (both using backend and database tables/fields) with the imported products averything seems to be exactly the same.

Comment: It would help to know exactly what you have already tried. For instance, have you tried the basics: set the product to In Stock, Set the qty to > 0, Set the visibility to visible catalog & Search. Set it as Enabled. Assigned it to a website etc?

Comment: Enabled OK, Visibility OK, qyt OK, assigned to a website OK... will edit the question to add some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm self answering. Thanks to @sulman that pointed in the correct direction.

Yes, visibility was ok for all the products and it was correctly settled as for both Catalog and Search. But the problem was that in our import script we didn't check for the existence and correct assignment of the attribute to the imported product. Therefore the attribute existed but it was not linked to the already existing visbility attribute.

Here a sample code in case is needed, see the opening `if (isset($attributeId))` that checks if the attribute exists or not.

```
if (isset($attributeId))
    {
        $entityAttributeModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api');
        $attributeList = $entityAttributeModel->items($attributeSetId);
        $attributeLink = $this->search($attributeList, 'attribute_id', $attributeId);

        if (sizeof($attributeLink) == 0)
        {
            $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');         
            $setup->addAttributeToGroup($this->getEntityTypeId(), $attributeSetId, $groupId, $attributeId);
        }       

        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
        $attribute = $model->load($attributeId);

    }
```